# Tmux key-table explanation

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I was reading through the tmux man pages in order to understand the different options for `bind-key` and bumped into the `-t` flag:

`If -t is present, key is bound in key-table: the binding for command mode with -c or for normal mode without.  To view the default bindings and possible commands, see the list-keys command.`

What's the `key-table` exactly? how does this command differs from the normal `bind-key` command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key-tables are named in the description of the `list-keys` command and described earlier in the man page:

- vi-edit, emacs-edit

  Used while editing a line at a command prompt.
  E.g. via `command-prompt`, `confirm-before`, or the “Goto Line”, “Search Up”, or “Search Down” prompts in copy-mode
- vi-choice, emacs-choice

  Used when choosing from lists.
  E.g. via `choose-client`, `choose-session`, `choose-window`, `choose-tree`, `choose-list`, `choose-buffer`, or `find-window`
- vi-copy, emacs-copy

  Used when viewing scrollback or other output.
  E.g. `copy-mode`, `run-shell` output, or errors from a startup configuration file or `source-file`.

The keys bound in these tables are active when the various “modes” are active. They do not require the Prefix key, since the “mode” itself supersedes any normal interaction with the active pane.

Additionally, the bindings in these tables are restricted to particular special-purpose commands (e.g. related to movement and editing), and each key can only be bound to a single command (i.e. `\;` can not be used to bind a key to a sequence of multiple commands).

These “mode commands” are not described in the man page, but you should be able to find most of them by inspecting the listings for the tables (e.g. `tmux list-keys -t emacs-copy`, et cetera) or from the source code (`mode-key.c`); their names are generally self-descriptive (e.g. `cursor-up`, `page-up`, `cancel`, et cetera).